# What are Modules in a project?

Tags: asp.net

Hi i want to know what is meant by modules in a project??how they are classified and how many modules we can have in a project?can anyone explain with simple examples??What modules we can have in a typical online shopping website?

Comment: Isn't the tutorial on web about modules good enough to give the idea of the module ? If not - what part of them you did not understand ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a _tutorial_ website, please kindly do some googling on the topic, i hope u'll find a bunch of examples...goodluck

Comment: I know this is not a tutorial website or i dint ask for tutorials here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net context I believe one can draw 2 meanings not sure what specific you are looking for.

One is modular programming by following design principles like "Separation of concerns", "Single Responsibility", "loose coupling". This means divide you code into classes based on these principles and further group these classes again based on these principles into modules.

In ASP.NET or C# or in general we create class library projects and use them across the entire project. Like all the logging functionality is put in some classes and these classes are include in an class library project which can be called "Logging module". Whenever you need logging in any of the project you can include this module and use the functionality.

Some examples:

- Web module for HTTP requests ( The WebApp)
- Repository and Data access Layer modules. (DAL code)
- Models module containing all the business entities.
- WebService modules for integrating with other apps.
- Logging for debugging and problem identification
- Infrastructure/Utility modules for utility like functionalities and
  application configuration.
- Business logic modules.
- Transaction gateway module.

Other way to define module in .net is they are PE files and I believe they have extension .netmodule which contain Metadata but they do not contain the assembly manifest. To use a module you have to create a PE file with the necessary assembly manifest.

Create a module:

```
csc /t:module ufo.cs
```

Create assembly using the module:

```
csc /t:library /addmodule:ufo.netmodule /out:airvehicles.dll helicopter.cs
```

Above 2 commands are from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not asking about modular programming i am asking about about the modules in a project as u said logging module...Each developer is assigned to those modules to write the code ex:e-commerce website or some banking application so i am asking about what kind of modules we can have in these kind of applications

Comment: This can very specific to an application. I have edited the above post for some that I can think of now.

Answer (score 0):

The module is an external code that you plugin on your site and runs in order to do some actions.

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/images/article/19389/020417_01.jpg))</sub>

We make and use modules to have the ability to share the actions of the module with others with out giving the source code, and vice versa, we use modules from other that we do not have access to the source code. Or we can simple use module for have the ability so simplify our code and remove it easy if we do not need it.

We can have as modules as we like, but each module place extra overhead on our code - after all is need to make more thinks there.

More about modules: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19389/HTTP-Handlers-and-HTTP-Modules-in-ASPNET.htm

How to create module: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996

Comment: Aristos i am not asking about http modules kind of thing i am just asking about what kind of modules will be there in a project like admin and user modules....